# exclude items based on field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view, sql-server-2019

I've created a view using the below script but one of the fields is pulling back information that I don't need. Within the 'IsServer' column, items that are servers are marked with a 1 and items that aren't servers are marked with a 0. Is there a way of creating the view and exclude items that are servers that are marked as 1 in the IsServer column? I'm unsure how to build this into the create view script.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Cherwell_Machines] AS 
SELECT dbo.rptComputers.HostName, 
       dbo.rptComputers.Vendor, 
       dbo.tblComputer.IsVirtual, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorCount, 
       dbo.tblComputer.IsServer, 
       dbo.rptComputers.BiosSerialNumber, 
       dbo.rptComputers.PhysicalMemory, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorType, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorSpeed, 
       dbo.rptComputers.MostFrequentUser, 
       dbo.tblComputer.Domain, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ClientVersion, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ClientInstallDate, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ClientConfigurationName, 
       dbo.rptComputers.BiosVersion, 
       dbo.rptComputers.BiosDate, 
       dbo.rptComputers.Manufacturer, 
       dbo.rptComputers.Model, 
       dbo.rptComputers.IsPortable, 
       dbo.rptComputers.OperatingSystem, 
       dbo.tblComputer.OSServicePack,
       dbo.rptComputers.ComputerStatusCode, 
       dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress AS 'MultipleIPAddress', 
                
CASE WHEN PATINDEX ('%[, ]%',dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress) > 0 THEN 
       left(dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress,(PATINDEX('%[, ]%',dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress))-1) 
       ELSE dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress 
       END  AS 'IPAddress',
                
       dbo.rptComputers.LastScanDate

FROM dbo.rptComputers INNER JOIN dbo.tblComputer ON dbo.rptComputers.CID = dbo.tblComputer.CID 
     AND dbo.rptComputers.ComputerID = dbo.tblComputer.ComputerID

GROUP BY dbo.rptComputers.HostName, 
         dbo.tblComputer.IsVirtual, 
         dbo.rptComputers.Vendor, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorCount, 
         dbo.rptComputers.BiosSerialNumber, 
         dbo.tblComputer.IsServer, 
         dbo.rptComputers.PhysicalMemory,
         dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorType, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorSpeed, 
         dbo.rptComputers.MostFrequentUser, 
         dbo.tblComputer.Domain,
         dbo.rptComputers.ClientVersion, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ClientInstallDate, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ClientConfigurationName, 
         dbo.rptComputers.BiosVersion, 
         dbo.rptComputers.BiosDate, 
         dbo.rptComputers.Manufacturer, 
         dbo.rptComputers.Model, 
         dbo.rptComputers.IsPortable, 
         dbo.rptComputers.OperatingSystem, 
         dbo.tblComputer.OSServicePack,
         dbo.rptComputers.ComputerStatusCode, 
         dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress, 
         dbo.rptComputers.LastScanDate
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. Stick to aliasing your columns and using those to qualify your columns instead. It makes your code *way* more succinct and thus readable. Also, why are you performing a `GROUP BY` here when there is no aggregation in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a filtered view; i.e., a view with a `WHERE` clause. Something like this (I marked off in comments the begin/end of my addition to your code):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Cherwell_Machines] AS 
SELECT dbo.rptComputers.HostName, 
       dbo.rptComputers.Vendor, 
       dbo.tblComputer.IsVirtual, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorCount, 
       dbo.tblComputer.IsServer, 
       dbo.rptComputers.BiosSerialNumber, 
       dbo.rptComputers.PhysicalMemory, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorType, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorSpeed, 
       dbo.rptComputers.MostFrequentUser, 
       dbo.tblComputer.Domain, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ClientVersion, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ClientInstallDate, 
       dbo.rptComputers.ClientConfigurationName, 
       dbo.rptComputers.BiosVersion, 
       dbo.rptComputers.BiosDate, 
       dbo.rptComputers.Manufacturer, 
       dbo.rptComputers.Model, 
       dbo.rptComputers.IsPortable, 
       dbo.rptComputers.OperatingSystem, 
       dbo.tblComputer.OSServicePack,
       dbo.rptComputers.ComputerStatusCode, 
       dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress AS 'MultipleIPAddress', 
                
CASE WHEN PATINDEX ('%[, ]%',dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress) > 0 THEN 
       left(dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress,(PATINDEX('%[, ]%',dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress))-1) 
       ELSE dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress 
       END  AS 'IPAddress',
                
       dbo.rptComputers.LastScanDate

FROM dbo.rptComputers INNER JOIN dbo.tblComputer ON dbo.rptComputers.CID = dbo.tblComputer.CID 
     AND dbo.rptComputers.ComputerID = dbo.tblComputer.ComputerID
/*begin change*/
WHERE tblComputer.IsServer = 0 
/*end change*/
GROUP BY dbo.rptComputers.HostName, 
         dbo.tblComputer.IsVirtual, 
         dbo.rptComputers.Vendor, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorCount, 
         dbo.rptComputers.BiosSerialNumber, 
         dbo.tblComputer.IsServer, 
         dbo.rptComputers.PhysicalMemory,
         dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorType, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ProcessorSpeed, 
         dbo.rptComputers.MostFrequentUser, 
         dbo.tblComputer.Domain,
         dbo.rptComputers.ClientVersion, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ClientInstallDate, 
         dbo.rptComputers.ClientConfigurationName, 
         dbo.rptComputers.BiosVersion, 
         dbo.rptComputers.BiosDate, 
         dbo.rptComputers.Manufacturer, 
         dbo.rptComputers.Model, 
         dbo.rptComputers.IsPortable, 
         dbo.rptComputers.OperatingSystem, 
         dbo.tblComputer.OSServicePack,
         dbo.rptComputers.ComputerStatusCode, 
         dbo.rptComputers.IPAddress, 
         dbo.rptComputers.LastScanDate
```

> Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15 Be sure to see the "limitations" section there, in case there's something in your environment which will not work here.

Comment: I'd still suggest fixing the 3+ part naming and removing the `GROUP BY` as there's no aggregation.

Comment: @Larnu I agree with your 2 concerns. While those are correct, they are beyond the scope of the question. The OP wanted to get a filtered result set as the View create script - which I answered. Your comment will be read by the OP and hopefully implemented.

Comment: *"While those are correct, they are beyond the scope of the question."* I would suggest it's what makes an "ok" or "good" answer "great".